# Chartjs isn't rendering bar chart, even though chart variable shows correctly when console logged

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I'm having an issue rendering a bar chart with Chartjs using Reactjs. When I console.logged the chart variable created in componentDidMount, it shows the correct labels and data (labels: (5) ["Very Positive", "Somewhat Positive", "Neutral", "Somewhat Negative", "Very Negative"] and data: (5) [10, 17, 35, 34, 4]). However, when I load the page, the bar chart doesn't display any data. Am I not rendering the bar chart correctly?

```
class BarChart extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        render: false,
        data : {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Number of Tweets by Sentiment Category",
                    backgroundColor: "blue",
                    data: []
                },
              ]
            }
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getGraphs();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state.data)
    let el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.chart);
    let ctx = el.getContext("2d");

    let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: this.state.data,
        options: {
            barValueSpacing: 20,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0
                    }
                }]
              }
            }
          }
        );
      console.log(chart)
      this.setState({ render: true })
      }

  getGraphs = async() => {

    let ticker = this.state.crypto;
    let name = this.state.name;

    let URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/getGraphs';

    let response = fetch(URL, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'name': name,
        'ticker': ticker,
      }
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((info) => {
      let data = this.state.data;

      data['labels'] = info.categories;
      data['datasets']['data'] = info.count;
      this.setState({ 'data': data })
    })
  }

  render() {
  return (
    <div className='card'>
      { this.state.render = true &&
        <canvas ref="chart" height="400px" />
      }
    </div>);

  } 
}

export default BarChart;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making the request for your data in the `componentWillMount` hook, but it is possible that you are getting the response after the component has been mounted (i.e. after the `componentDidMount` has been executed).

The use of [`componentWillMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) to make requests is discouraged (note that the method is considered legacy and you should avoid using it):

> Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method. For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead.

Also, your render method is assigning a value to `this.state.render` instead of checking if it is true or not to render the `canvas` element.

Lastly, the data stored in the `state` of your component should be data that affects the DOM you want to render (since calling `setState` causes the `render` method to execute). But in your code, you are rendering your chart through a `canvas`. Therefore, the data for your chart is not affecting the DOM you are rendering.

Taking all the previous points into account, you can render an empty `canvas` element from the start (i.e. no need for `state.render`), make the request in the `componentDidMount` hook and once you have the info, render the chart:

```
class BarChart extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getGraphs().then(info => {
            const data = {
                labels: info.categories,
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Number of Tweets by Sentiment Category",
                    backgroundColor: "blue",
                    data: info.count
                }]
            };

            this.renderChart(data);
        })
    }

    renderChart(data) {
        let el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.chart);
        let ctx = el.getContext("2d");

        let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: data,
            options: {
                barValueSpacing: 20,
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            min: 0
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    }

    getGraphs() {
        let ticker = this.state.crypto;
        let name = this.state.name;

        let URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/getGraphs';

        return fetch(URL, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'name': name,
                'ticker': ticker,
            }
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='card'>
                <canvas ref="chart" height="400px" />
            </div>
        );
    } 
}

export default BarChart;
```

Also, I noticed that in the `getGraphs` method you are reading the `crypto` and `name` attributes from the `state`, but in your question you are not declaring them.

Comment: Hi mgarcia, thanks for the detailed response. I can definitely see why componenetWillMount could be problematic. I switched the code but it doesn't let me use await outside of an async function. Is there some other way to make creating info conditional on getGraphs completing?

Comment: Ups, my bad! I updated the code. Basically, we return the promise in the `getGraphs` method and then in the `componentDidMount` we wait until it is resolved in order to call the `renderChart` method.

Comment: This worked! Thanks for the help mgarcia. I didn't think about using .then in that scenario. Much appreciated, I've been working on figuring this out for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

This line seems to be incorrect. You are assigning a value here and not checking if its true.

```
{ this.state.render = true &&
        <canvas ref="chart" height="400px" />
      }
```

Change it to :

```
{ this.state.render &&
        <canvas ref="chart" height="400px" />
      }
```

It may not be the root cause, but just want to point it out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Vijay. I just tried the change but then I get the error 'Cannot read property 'getContext' of null'